# Does Firefox contact Websites on Open to Retrieve Bookmark Favicons

Tags: security, firefox, anonymous

Security Flaw? Firefox contacts Websites on Open to Retrieve Bookmark Favicons?

My job requires anonymous intervallic visits to Muslim Jihad sites to track terror trends on Islamic blogs and forums. So I bookmark the sites. Now, every time I open Firefox, the Muslim Jihad site will get a reminder of my footprint? We all remember what happened to Theo Van Gogh for less.

Am I right in thinking that my university, internet provider and other folk sniffing addresses (IRS, NSA and other anti-Conservative groups), are also reminded even if I've not visited recently, just because I maintain a visible bookmark which contacts the favicon address when Firefox opens? An address such as:
https://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico

Or does Firefox pull the icon once and store it locally? But I notice icons changing and refreshing: that's not possible, of course, with a single local copy.  Is this understanding correct?

Comment: They're saved locally in a SQLite database AFAIK. Maybe they're updated in the db if you visit a site and a newer favicon is available, I don't know for sure. I'm pretty sure FF does not attempt to 'refresh' any stored bookmark favicons each time you open it though. If browsing as stealth as possible is important for your job, your boss(es) should get you a VPN and you should use JonDoFox instead of barebones Firefox.

Comment: I read about the SQLlite storage but the articles I read indicated that only the URL was saved and not the jpg or .ico file. And it's precisely this saved URL that gets hit each time you open Firefox - that's the concern. I wouldn't care except 1/5 of the time I speak out against stoning I get death threats. So this issue is more than academic in this day and age.

Comment: Still Looking for a definitive answer to the question: Does Firefox reach out and touch webservers each new session in order to pull the .ico files used in its bookmarks. So far we've only established that the URLS are stored in the SQLite database. What's unclear is if the icons themselves are stored or recurringly fetched. This is not a small matter but a huge privacy compromise for the sake of bookmarks.

Comment: No it doesn't, it wouldn't be a practical thing to do. Open a command prompt next time you start FF and type 'netstat' to monitor internet connections to confirm. Ask someone from Mozilla if you're not satisfied with the answer.